# System dependencies have not been satisfied, apt python-mock, apt python-coverage

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am new to ros. I am using rosbuild to compile gmapping package, https://github.com/ros-perception/slam_gmapping/tree/groovy-devel,it tells me many lines of "No Makefile in package...". Then I use *rosdep check gmapping* command , the terminal show me
"System dependencies have not been satisfied
apt   python-mock
apt   python-covergae"
What's more, my ros version is groovy, operation system is ubuntu 12.04.
What should I do next?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214890/system-dependencies-have-not-been-satisfied,-apt-python-mock,-apt-python-coverage/) by [Suyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23397/suyan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2015-07-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Now I have installed **python-mock** and **python-coverage** , and rosdep show me that  **All system dependencies have been satisfied**. However, when I use rosmake gmapping to build it, the terminal still gives me many lines of "No Makefile in package...". What  can I do next?

---

Originally posted by [Suyan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23397/suyan/) with karma: 26 on 2015-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bhavyadoshi26](https://answers.ros.org/users/26692/bhavyadoshi26/) on 2016-04-28**:
How did you install python-mock and python-coverage?